# Can a iOS app load a webview with youtube?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, http-live-streaming

I am developing an iOS app. In that I am loading couple of youtube videos using HTML5 using webview.

I am bit concerned about the fact that apple will reject the apps that are loading some big videos directly without HTTP live streaming.

So, is my approach wrong? Shall I load youtube video directly? Is the youtube providing HTTP livestreaming by itself?

I am curious to know these stuffs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to load the YouTube video in HTML WebViews. Many apps do it this way.

The key thing to remember is that you are not allowed to autoplay videos, they have to be user initiated i.e. they have to press the play button.

**Edit**:
Please check [**this**](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html) official page

Comment: Checkout: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html